# how to access /obtain object elements from an observable array

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

I would like to know how I can obtain an obtain an objects item(LicenseNo) from an observable array. I have pasted my code below , after inserting breakpoints I noticed that I am currently getting the entire objects array as in [LicenseNo , name , allocated route , licenseDate]  I just want to get the LicenseNo

```
function getDriverList(item) {

if (!pageViewModel.isAuthenticated()) return;
var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
var LicenseNo = ko.observableArray([]);
$.when(getSecureData("/api/FleetDrivers/" + item.NationalID))
    .done(function (resp) {
        pageViewModel.vehicelDriversVM.DriverList(resp.FleetDriverList);
        if (pageViewModel.vehicelDriversVM.DriverList(resp.FleetDriverList).length > 0) {
              LicenseNo  = pageViewModel.vehicelDriversVM.FleetDriverList()[0];   
            alert('The first driver's License Number is ' LicenseNo;

        }

    });
return dfd.promise(); 
 }
```

the code above didnt work so I have pasted the correct one below for anyone who might run into a similar prob

```
function getDriverList(item) {

if (!pageViewModel.isAuthenticated()) return;
var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
var LicenseNo = ko.observableArray();
$.when(getSecureData("/api/FleetDrivers/" + item.NationalID))
    .done(function (resp) {
        pageViewModel.vehicelDriversVM.DriverList(resp.FleetDriverList);
         LicenseNo  = resp.FleetDriverList[1];   
         alert('The first driver's License Number is ' + LicenseNo);



    });
return dfd.promise();
```

enter code here

Comment: try this `pageViewModel.vehicelDriversVM.FleetDriverList()[0].LicenseNo()`

Comment: @super cool     I think there might be something wrong with this line                `if (pageViewModel.vehicelDriversVM.DriverList(resp.FleetDriverList).length > 0) ` should it instead be like this      `if (pageViewModel.vehicelDriversVM.FleetDriverList.length > 0) { ` because I am getting an error that says length is undefined

Comment: i need to guess here without seeing your vm completely . try this `pageViewModel.vehicelDriversVM()[0].FleetDriverList().length` i am hoping `vehicelDriversVM` is observableArray

Comment: edited my post to include the the working function

Comment: Post it as an answer so future readers are not stuck without reading all the comments. Point out where the problem was and what was needed to fix it, not only post the corrected code.